# How can I prevent child processes from being spawned infinitely in a module (control.py) that I call from another module (Calling.py)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, child-process

I have a module named control.py in which I use the following abridged code-

```
def parallel_execution():
    if __name__=="__main__":
       process=multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_function) ##the worker_function has been defined appropriately
       process.start()
       process.join()
    return
def main(main_args):
    if multiprocessing_flag == True:
       parallel_execution()
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I have another module called Calling.py from which I wish to execute the multiprocessing functionality defined in parallel_execution().
The problem is if I use the `(if __name__=='__main__' )`block then I cannot call the control.py from another script. If I still use `runpy.run_module("control",run_name='__main__')` I get an error saying worker_function cannot be pickled.

How can I call control.py so that I can run the parallel_execution function? In other words, is there a way to prevent my parent process from spawning child processes infinitely without using `if __name__=='__main__'` so that I can still call control.py from Calling.py ?

Comment: I don't understand what `if __name__=="__main__":` is doing in `parallel_execution`. If you remove that and have Calling.py import control, it should work. Except...., if you join the process, the function waits until the subprocess is complete, which isn't exactly parallel.

Comment: Disclaimer-I am a newbie to Python : I wrote the if __name__=="__main__" to prevent the parent process from spawning subprocesses indefinitely(recursively). I want to run my code on Windows as well. There, it seems, the calling code simply copies the entire module. So without the if name==main block, each child process will continue to call multiple children recursively.(At least that's my understanding).

Comment: @tdelaney- I am actually calling processes in a loop and appending each process to a list. Then after the 1st loop of creating processes is complete I am using a second loop to join each process . I haven't shown the 2 loops intentionally to keep the focus on the real problem(according to me).

Comment: Some clarification on that... its usual to put the `"__main__"` restriction on top level code that executes the functions, not the functions themselves. The module level protection that makes sure main, and hence parallel_execution, are not called in the spawned process should be sufficient. `runpy.run_module` complicates things a bit, but the module level guard still works in that case.

Comment: A python program is a top level script, `"__main__"` plus any number of imported modules. Only the script itself needs the if protecting the program.

Comment: @tdelaney- Thanks for your comments. They helped me.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to prevent child processes from being spawned recursively- One of those is the `if __name__=='__main__'` block of code that prevents the child process from spawning further processes.
The other method has to do with the way child processes work-as a matter of fact, when child processes are called using either multiprocessing.Process or multiprocessing.Pool(which internally uses multiprocessing.Process) they inherit the script containing the target function passed to the multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_function,args=....,....) . So if the script containig the target (worker_function) is defined in a separate module and then imported, then this problem of child-processes getting spawned recursively is eliminated.

Reference- https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/basics.html#importable-target-functions

So, in my question above, all I have to do is put the worker_function in a python module separate from the "`control.py`" module.